# Facebook login on Android doesn't open session

Tags: android, facebook

I'm new to facebook development for Android. I have started with [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)
but my app can't connect to facebook. It always returns false in *if (session.isOpened())*

I have searched and read a lot about this issue and I have realised that in most cases the problem is the key hash. I have checked my hash with this code

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "my package", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "Hash: " + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

And also through command prompt:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore > C:\openssl\bin\debug.txt
C:\openssl\bin\openssl sha1 -binary C:\openssl\bin\debug.txt > C:\openssl\bin\debug_sha.txt
C:\openssl\bin\openssl base64 -in C:\openssl\bin\debug_sha.txt > C:\openssl\bin\debug_base64.txt
```

I have obtained same hash with both ways, and entered it on the field "Key Hashes" of my facebook's app. The other fields are filled with my package and class. Sandbox mode is active.

This is my exact code:

```
facebookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //FACEBOOK LOGIN HERE
            // start Facebook Login
            Session.openActiveSession(StartMenu.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
               // callback when session changes state
               @Override
               public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

                   Log.d("FACEBOOK","Session opened?: " + session.isOpened());
                   if (session.isOpened()) {

                       // make request to the /me API
                       Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                         // callback after Graph API response with user object
                         @Override
                         public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                             if (user != null) {
                                  //USER LOGGED
                                 Log.d("FACEBOOK","Logged in!");
                                 facebookButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.facebook_thumbs_up);
                             }
                         }
                       }).executeAsync();

                   }

               }
            });

        }
    });
```

Note that I'm using *newMeRequest* + *executeAsync()* method instead of the deprecated one *executeMeRequestAsync* but I have tested also deprecated method with same result.

Also, I have coded:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And also I have my app_id tag on strings.xml and added meta-data and activity tags for facebook in manifest file.

I'm using sdk 3.6.0.

I have tested in three devices, two with facebook app installed, one without app. In all devices my app can't connect.

What I'm doing wrong??

Thanks in advance, and excuse me for my english.

UPDATE: Solved!! I made a bad reference to app_id string (shame on me). However I have noticed that if you have FB App installed, it will not show any information about that and logcat messages could be a little confusing, so I will test all facebook stuff in a device without fb app. Thanks guys!

Comment: Check the LogCat output, the Facebook SDK will give you more information. Post its contents here if you need further help.